# Product Price is Showing at Bottom of the product Images in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, https, woocommerce, themes

The product prices are showing up below the product images... the issue can be viewed in the image below and also from the shared url...
anyone familiar with error??
Theme is eightstore-lite

Image of the issue
[image: Image of the issue]

https://a2zdeals.pk/product/charge-2-wireless-activity-heart-rate-tracker/

Comment: What is the error in it? Do you want to show the price in some other place?

Comment: the price should be in front of the product images but it's showing below the images as shown in the image

Comment: In front of the product image, which place you are referring to?If you want to change that you have to make woo-commerce products details page.